# python【 matplotlib ＋ jupyter 】以外の方法でグラフ表示を行う方法はありますか？

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

matplotlib ＋ jupyter以外の方法でグラフを画面に表示することが可能な方法はありますか？

元のやり方の場合でも同様に質問ですが、pyinstaller等でexe化しようとする.pyファイル内での記述で完結可能ですか？

Comment: 対象範囲が広すぎるように見えるので、こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に内容や条件を明確化して1問1答になるようにしてみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ,[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) リスト的な情報ならこちらの記事とかが使えるかもしれません。[12 Python Data Visualization Libraries to Explore for Business Analysis](https://mode.com/blog/python-data-visualization-libraries/), [Python Data Visualization Libraries](https://qiita.com/yigarashi/items/2cbbeade3efd17500150)

Comment: 広いでしょうか…？pythonのjupyter環境下じゃないと実行できない方法以外の実行方法があるか？だけなのですが…。

Comment: あ、python以外の言語は無しです

Comment: この質問内容の一番簡単な答えは「ある/ない」とか「可能/不可能」だけで済んだことになります。しかしそれでは満足できないでしょう？何をどう使うかとかこの場合はどうすれば良いのかとか。そうするとコメントなり質問の追記なりで続くことになりますよ。

Comment: @kunif まずは、有るかどうか、有るとしたら例えばどんな物なのか、知りたいという事でしょう。
具体的な、「この場合はどうすれば」のような疑問が生じたら別質問として投稿してもらえば良いと思います。
少々気を回しすぎでは？

Comment: @mjy さん、既にmatplotlib+Jupyterで動作(あるいは参考に)しているプログラムがあるなら(質問のニュアンス的にありそうだったので)、そのソースコードやリンクを提示して質問してもらう方が早くて具体的だと思ったんですがね。

Comment: 多分私の説明の仕方が悪いのでご迷惑をおかけしました。jupyterを使用してmatplotlibを使用したグラフの表示をする一連のプログラムをネットで見つけることは可能なのですが、jupyterがインストールされていない（ないしpythonがインストールされていない）環境のPCで実行することはできないと思うのでそういう環境でもpython言語ベースで開発する方法があるのかな？という疑問です。（その場合exe化してパッケージングするくらいしか思いつかなかったので。）いったんもらった内容を調べるので本件クローズで大丈夫です。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

#### Matplotlib の場合

[Backends](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) に UI のバックエンドに関して述べられています。PyQt/PySide、PyGObject、Tkinter、wxPython、macOS/Cocoa などが有るようです。

そもそも、 Jupyter を用いる方法がオプションというか、発展的な利用方法だと思います。[チュートリアル](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html)や [Quick start guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html) に従うと、デフォルトのバックエンドとして Qt や Tk などが使われると思います。

自作の UI に組込む場合は、[Embedding Matplotlib in graphical user interfaces](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/index.html) で解説されています。

PyInstaller での exe 化のやり易さは、UI ライブラリにより様々と思いますが、メジャーなツールキットであれば、それぞれ解説が見つかります。

Answer (score 2):

#### GUI 環境を利用する方法

[GUI Programming in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) にクロスプラットホーム・フレームワークやプラットフォーム固有のフレームワークが載ってます

グラフの描画なら, UI としてではなく描画のみで, 結局 Matplotlib で行うことになるでしょう
(ユーザースクリプトで線を引くなどは可能だが, グラフになるとそれなり大変になるので)
その場合の GUI環境としては Qt, Tkinter などが候補に上がるはず

その辺りは別解で記されているとおりで,
付け加えるなら表示の際 **別ウィンドウ**が立ち上がる … くらい

#### Webブラウザーを利用する方法

(実行環境に Webブラウザーが用意されてるなら …)

canvas や SVG などの機能で描画を行う はずで制御は JavaScript 経由,
matplotlib以外に次のようなグラフ・ライブラリーがあります

- [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/)
- [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/)

Python側は [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/) など。
必要に応じて [webbrowser --- 便利なウェブブラウザコントローラー](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/webbrowser.html) など使用するとよいかも

(Flask and (Bokeh or Plotly) など検索すると記事が見つかる)

#### Matplotlib で UIなしの方法

Matplotlibのバックエンドには 2 つの種類, UI バックエンド, (画像ファイルを作成するための)ハードコピー・バックエンドがあります

> There are two types of backends: user interface backends (for use in PyQt/PySide, PyGObject, Tkinter, wxPython, or macOS/Cocoa); also referred to as "interactive backends") and hardcopy backends to make image files (PNG, SVG, PDF, PS; also referred to as "non-interactive backends").

後者の中で, `Agg` レンダラー ([Agg which uses the Anti-Grain Geometry](https://agg.sourceforge.net/antigrain.com/) ライブラリー) を使用すると, 手軽に(**小さいフットプリントで**) ファイル作成が可能

[image: imgcat で画像表示]

---

また, sixelに対応しているターミナルエミュレーターがあるなら以下を利用し直接描画も可能です

- matplotlib-sixel (backend) (複数見つかったのでオリジナル不明なためリンクは省く)
- [sixelplot](https://github.com/kktk-KO/sixelplot)
- [sixel-gnuplot](https://github.com/csdvrx/sixel-gnuplot)

Comment: GUI 環境を利用 - 別ウィンドウで表示 … するには, Jupyterでセルの先頭あたりに `%matplotlib qt`  入れておくと雰囲気わかります